# Python find duplicates in the first col of a 2D list and remove one of them based on the second col

Tags: python, list

I'm looking for a way to remove duplicates from a 2D list, but based on the highest value in the second column. I know how to do it in several for loops, but I'm searching for a O(N) solution. 
Sample Input:

```
inputLst = [[100,150]
          ,[150,140]
          ,[200,180]
          ,[300,150]
          ,[300,100]
          ,[320,180]]
```

Output should be:

```
OutputLst = [[100,150]
           ,[150,140]
           ,[200,180]
           ,[300,150]
           ,[320,180]]
```

This is the code I have now:

```
        SortLst = [[100,150],[150,140],[200,180],[300,150],[300,100],[320,180]]
        lst = []
        lastRow = SortLst[0]
        for row in SortLst+[0,0]:
            if row[0] != lastRow[0]:
                lst.append(lastRow)
                lastRow = row
            elif row [1] > lastRow[1]:
                lastRow =  row
```

The Sortlst is sorted by:

```
SortLst = sorted(zip(self.WavelengthPanel.GetValues(col=1),self.Shuttertime))
```

Comment: take a look at `itertools.groupby()` (https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)

Comment: Then when input is `[[100,110], [100,120]]`, should output be `[[100,120]]`?

Comment: Yes then the output should be [[100,120]]

Comment: OK, important to know, the `inputLst` is already sorted?

Comment: You know sorting always will be _O(N_ log _N)_.

Comment: I have to sort the lst anyway futher on in the code, but I was just wondering if there is a more pythonic way of solving this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at this

```
from pprint import pprint

input_lst = [[100, 150],
             [150, 140],
             [200, 180],
             [300, 150],
             [300, 100],
             [320, 180]]

output_lst = dict()

for n, v in input_lst:
    if n in output_lst:    # O(1)
        output_lst[n] = max(output_lst[n], v)    # O(1)
    else:
        output_lst[n] = v    # The question is, what is the complexity of this operation 

pprint(output_lst, width=10)
```

Output

```
{100: 150,
 150: 140,
 200: 180,
 300: 150,
 320: 180}
```

You can easily transform the output to a list.